# How am I supposed to pronounce the "ct" in Church's latin

Tags: pronunciation

for example, the word "fructus": should I say fruCTus or just fruTus?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Church Latin" usually refers to the Italian-based pronunciation of Latin that has been promoted by the Roman Catholic Church since at least the time of Pope Pius X.

There is no significant difference between this pronunciation system and the reconstructed ancient pronunciation of Latin regarding the pronunciation of "ct" in the word "fructus". It is [kt] in both: a [k] sound, as in the word *canis,* followed by a [t] sound, as in the word *tua.*

The sequence "ct" is always pronounced [kt] in the classical pronunciation of Latin. It is generally pronounced [kt] in the Italian/church pronunciation, with the exception of "cti", where "ct" is pronounced [kt͡s] when another vowel letter follows the I (as in *factio* [ˈfakt͡sio], or *aequinoctium*).

An Italian would, of course, pronounce this sequence according to an Italian accent. Accents differ across Italy, but you can find a [detailed transcription of one possible Italian pronunciation of Latin on the website of Professor Luciano Canepari](https://www.canipa.net/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=en:latin_pronunciation_20180219.pdf). Canepari narrowly transcribes the pronunciation of the word *amictum* as [aˈmik̵ːtum] in his "CanIPA" transcription system, showing lengthening of /k/ in these circumstances in "Academic Italian" pronunciation. Canepari says in his [guide to Italian pronunciation](https://www.canipa.net/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=en:italian_pronunciation_c.pdf) that "From a phonetic point of view, neutral Italian, in a tune, undergoes the lengthening of the last element of the phono-syllable" (page 84). (Canepari includes a stroke across the "k", which I've tried to reproduce, which is his way of indicating a prevelar consonant. This would be a non-phonemic allophone of /k/, caused I guess in *amictum* by partial assimilation to the preceding [i]—in which case we wouldn't expect to find it in *fructus*.) For a non-Italian speaker, trying to reproduce minutiae like these when speaking Latin could be considered overkill.